# Convert Java objects to JSON with specific fields

Tags: json, jackson, gson

I want to create two different JSON documents and each contains 5 fields. I have a POJO class with 10 attributes. I want to form json1 with 5 attributes and json2 with 5 attributes using that POJO class. Is there any way to construct these objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider writing two separate wrapper classes which each expose the fields you want for the two cases, and pass the pojo as a constructor arg.

So, one of them exposes one set of properties and might look like this:

```
public class JsonObject1 {
    private MyPojo myPojo;
    public JsonObject1(MyPojo myPojo) {
        this.myPojo = myPojo;
    }

    public void getProperty1() {
        return myPojo.getProperty1();
    }
    ......
}
```

and the other is similar, but exposes the other subset of properties.

Alternatively, you could add two methods (possibly to your POJO, or possibly to a service class that is exposing the POJO) that each returns a `Map` (eg a `HashMap`) where you've copied across the specific properties you want for each view, and then convert those Maps to JSON. This is less "model-driven", but might be less work overall. Thanks to @fvu for this observation!

```
public Map<String, Object> getPojoAsMap1() {
    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put("property1", pojo.getProperty1());
    ....
    return m;
}
```

It's also possible that the two different JSON representations are trying to tell you that your POJO should be split up into two POJOs - sometimes things like this are hints about how your code could be improved. But it depends on the circumstances, and it might not apply in this case.

Comment: As an alternative (less work but a bit messier) OP could do the same using eg a HashMap as intermediate container.

Comment: @fvu yep, fair point - shall I add that in, or do you want to add your own answer?

Comment: Just go ahead, it's just a variation on your answer, so it's not that useful to create another answer just for that.

Comment: @fvu Done. Thanks!